How to validate string format using regexp?
I have a String format like this
"[constant://foo;0][constant://bar;3]"

I use code like this to parse it:
val matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[constant([^;]*);([0-3])]", 
Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(gpLinkValue)
while (matcher.find()) {
    ....
   val part1 = matcher.group(1)
   ...
   val part2 = matcher.group(2).toLong()
   doSomeStuff(part1, part2)
}

The issue here that the string like:
[[constant://foo;0][constant://bar;3]]

Will be considered as valid and technically it is correct but from business standpoint this string has broken format.
More details:

Input string might have arbitary amount of [...]
I want to prevalidate the whole string before the parsing.If it is not valid I want to throw exception.

How can I achieve it ?
should I use additional regexp for that purpose?
P.S.
I tried to validate like this:
val str= "[constant://qwe,qdsf;0][constant://ololo1,ololo2,ololo3;3]"
val matcher = Pattern.compile(
    "\\[constant([^;]*);([0-3])]{0,99}",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE,
).matcher(str)
require(matcher.matches()) { "Can't parse. Invalid format" }

But this code lead to exception
another way is adding brackets:
  val str= "[constant://qwe,qdsf;0][constant://ololo1,ololo2,ololo3;3]"
    val matcher = Pattern.compile(
        "(\\[constant([^;]*);([0-3])]){0,99}",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE,
    ).matcher(str)
    require(matcher.matches()) { "Can't parse string as gpLink attribute value. Invalid format" }

validation is passed but further parsing fails:
   val str = "[constant://qwe,qdsf;0][constant://ololo1,ololo2,ololo3;3]"
    val matcher = Pattern.compile(
        "(\\[constant([^;]*);([0-3])]){0,99}",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE,
    ).matcher(str)
    require(matcher.matches()) { "Can't parse string as gpLink attribute value. Invalid format" }

    val links = listOf<String>().toMutableList()

    matcher.reset()
    matcher.find()
    links.add(matcher.group(0))
    links.add(matcher.group(1))
    links.add(matcher.group(2))
    links.add(matcher.group(3))
    matcher.find()
    links.add(matcher.group(0))
    links.add(matcher.group(1))
    links.add(matcher.group(2))
    links.add(matcher.group(3))
    
    links



The second string you provide is valid according to your regex, so not sure what the question is. Do you mean to ask "how can I change this regex to match the first string but not the second?" If so please also be more elaborate as to which strings should be valid (is the entire string just these blocks with no other characters allowed before/between/after, etc).

It is not a duplicate at all

Can you be more specific please, like  @somethingsomething already asked. Why is your second string broken format, because it contains double brackets at start and end? Could it also be like [[constant://foo;0][constant://bar;1][constant://bar;2]] and here you would want to match the middle item? (only one bracket to the right and left)

If you need to validate a string containing one or more occurrences of your pattern, use Pattern.compile("^(?:\\[constant([^\\]\\[;]*);([0-3])])+$")

@bobble bubble the string you provided [[...][....]] is considered as broken so function should throw exception

@gstackoverflow So you want to pre-validate the format of the full string e.g. [...] or even [...][...][...] (like Wiktors recommendation) and if it matches use doSomeStuff(part1, part2) with the captured parts, of each matching [...] item  and there can be an arbitrary amount of [...] items is that correct?

@bobble bubble I am working with @Wiktor example right now.
Yes, there can be arbitary amount of  [...]
Yes, I want to prevalidate the format of the whole string and if it is ok then I want to parse

You might want to provide the information in the question as well. I voted for reopen, maybe Wiktor will put an answer or someone else, as it sounds clear now.

@Wiktor Stribiżew If I am not mistaken you provided regexp of invalid pattern [[...][...]...]

I don't know if you can do the matching on each repetition in Java, I guess not. Probably you would need to use a \G based regex. First check the full string at start. If it's valid, chain matches like this: (?:\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:\[constant[^;]*;[0-3]])*$))\[constant([^;]*);([0-3])] (regex101). Maybe easier to use two steps, first validate with something like Wiktor's regex, then parse items.

@bobble bubble please read topic update

Is the string between "constant://" and ; allowed to contain a ]?

@k314159 substring between constant:// and ; mustn't contain ]

See if this update helps (in regex101 click on "code generator" on the left side below "tools"). I'm heading out for dinner now.

@bobble bubble it is a wonderful service - we investigate it. Regarding the solution you provided I have concerns. 1. It accepts strings with double brackets like [[...]] but expected result is a fail. 2. There are /n between [...]. It is also considered as a format break

If the brackets can be nested then this is not a regular language and cannot be matched with a regular expression. But if you simply need to verify in advance that the string "[[" does not appear in the input, that can easily be done without regular expressions. Just use if (!str.contains("[[")

@gstackoverflow If it must not contain \n you need to add it to the negated class. It should not accept strings with double brackets, one more updated demo (dinner coming). ️

Another update with \A and \z for matching start/end of the string rather than lines (this does not accept multiline input for testing, click the code generator for pattern as Java String).

I think you could shorten it a bit, not needed to do the precise check twice -> updated demo Or you break it up into two steps: 1.) Check full string \A(?:\[constant[^\n;\]\[]*;[0-3]]){1,99}\z if it matches 2.) Extract your items \[\w+([^;]*);(\d)] - probably this is the more practical way...

My regex was fine for validating, you must have tested it wrong. I will post the code with the regex that should work.

To pre-validate before extraction, you need to use a \G based regex with a lookahead at the start of string checking that contains a pattern to validate the string first.
It looks like
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:\[constant[^\]\[;]*;[0-3]])+$))\[constant([^\]\[;]*);([0-3])]

See the regex demo.
Details:

(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:\[constant[^\]\[;]*;[0-3]])+$)) - either the position after a successful match (\G(?!^)) or start of the string that contains one or more repetitions (if you need to validate only 0 to 99, replace +$ with {0,99}$) of [constant (matched with \[constant), zero or more chars other than [, ] and ; (matched with [^\]\[;]*), then a ; and then a digit from 0 to 3 (matched with [0-3])
\[constant([^\]\[;]*);([0-3])] - a single item pattern as above, just containing additional capturing groups to hold the value from [constant up to the ; char and the digit from 0 to 3 after the ;.

Here is a way to parse the strings you have:
val str = "[constant://qwe,qdsf;0][constant://ololo1,ololo2,ololo3;3]"
val matcher = """(?i)(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:\[constant[^\]\[;]*;[0-3]])+$))\[constant([^\]\[;]*);([0-3])]""".toRegex()
println( matcher.findAll(str).map{it.value}.toList() )
// => [[constant://qwe,qdsf;0], [constant://ololo1,ololo2,ololo3;3]]
println( matcher.findAll(str).map{it.groupValues[1]}.toList() )
// => [://qwe,qdsf, ://ololo1,ololo2,ololo3]
println( matcher.findAll(str).map{it.groupValues[2]}.toList() )
// => [0, 3]

See the Kotlin demo online.
Just in case you are worried to see [[constant://qwe,qdsf;0], [constant://ololo1,ololo2,ololo3;3]] as the result of the first println, please note it is just how the array/list is printed to the console, the values inside the list are just what you extracted from the input string.

Sorry for stupid question. Should I use different regexp expresstions for parse and validate ?

@gstackoverflow It depends on what you can afford. If you can use simpler regexps to do validation and then extraction, it may make more sense.

Yes, I can use different regexp. I don't see any limitations.
To be honest I try to work with gpLink format:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpol/08090b22-bc16-49f4-8e10-f27a8fb16d18

For some reasons this code returns false:
("[LDAP://CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;0]").matches(Regex.fromLiteral("(?:\\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:\\[LDAP://[^\\]\\[;]*;[0-3]])+\$))\\[LDAP://([^\\]\\[;]*);([0-3])]")) 
Although your demo says that it should be true

please tak a look:
https://pl.kotl.in/gyHWdVS0i?theme=darcula

https://regex101.com/r/BbCLD1/1

For some reasons the first line is invalid
https://pl.kotl.in/lvjFhqfNY

but if I copy paste is here https://regex101.com/r/BbCLD1/1
it works....

@gstackoverflow Let's stop at one example. Say, you have [LDAP://CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;0]. What exact output (type, etc.) do you want to get as a result?

lets stop on this example:
https://play.kotlinlang.org/embed?short=lvjFhqfNY
expected result - true for both strings

@gstackoverflow It is easy, just use what I shared in the comment below the question, val matcher = """(?:\[LDAP([^\]\[;]*);([0-3])])+""".toRegex(). Since you are using .matches() method, you do not need ^ and $ as it requires the whole string to match the regex.

Well toRegex vs matches is clear. What wrong with play.kotlinlang.org/embed?short=lvjFhqfNY  ?

@gstackoverflow I already explained that: .matches() requires a full string match. [LDAP://CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;2][LDAP://CN={6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;0] contains two matches.

let me explain my expected result:

[LDAP://CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;3] -> true
[LDAP://CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;2][LDAP://CN={6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;0] -> true
[LDAP://CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;2]OLOLOLOLO[LDAP://CN={6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;0] ->false


4.[[LDAP://CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;3]] -> false

You already have a solution: val matcher = """(?:\[LDAP([^\]\[;]*);([0-3])])+""".toRegex().

Oh, thanks. It really works
https://pl.kotl.in/nFTp8RPtN

Could you please explain the meaning of leading "?:"
I googled it and looks like it makes the next symbol optional but this string is not matched:
"LDAP://CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company;3]"
https://pl.kotl.in/MvI_hhDHl

@gstackoverflow See What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?
